# Return type mismatch (or not)

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this, return-type

I'm a bit confused by this piece of code. It's actually mine, but still I couldn't understand why this compiles without at least any warning.

```
#include <iostream>
class Line {
    private:
        int length;
    public:
        Line(void);
        Line(int);
        int getLength(void);
        Line& operator = (const Line&);
};
Line::Line(int a) : length(a) {}
int Line::getLength(void) { return length; }
Line& Line::operator = (const Line& line)           // The function return type is reference of a value of the Line type.
{
    length = line.length;
    return *this;                                   // The function actually returns dereferenced (*this) value.
}
int main(void)
{
    Line line {2};
    Line line_a {0};
    line_a = line;
    std::cout << line_a.getLength() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The only difference is the absence of ampersand. It still compiles

```
#include <iostream>
class Line {
    private:
        int length;
    public:
        Line(void);
        Line(int);
        int getLength(void);
        Line operator = (const Line&);
};
Line::Line(int a) : length(a) {}
int Line::getLength(void) { return length; }
Line Line::operator = (const Line& line)            // The function return type is reference of a value of the Line type.
{
    length = line.length;
    return *this;                                   // The function actually returns dereferenced (*this) value.
}
int main(void)
{
    Line line {2};
    Line line_a {0};
    line_a = line;
    std::cout << line_a.getLength() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: So, could you please explain in more details *what* exactly do you see as strange in this code? Your function properly returns a reference. All is well.

Comment: @AnT *this is dereferencing and the asterisk doesn't have any type related purpose. I tried using parentheses `code`return (*this)`code` and it worked. so it's actually returns an object, not a reference to an object.
(I'm kind of overworking these days and I'm bit tired, so in this condition it takes me double effort to comprehend some obvious things.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Let's consider this code:**

```
#include <iostream>
int global_variable = 8;
int function(void)
{
    return global_variable;
}
int main(void)
{
    function() = 16;        // Compiling this code would give error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment.
    std::cout <<  global_variable << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But, if we modify this code little bit and we would change the function return type to reference to int - this will change `lvalue` to `rvalue` (`int somenumber` is `lvalue`, `int& somenumber` is `rvalue`).

```
#include <iostream>
int global_variable = 8;
int& function(void)
{
    return global_variable;
}
int main(void)
{
    function() = 16;
    std::cout <<  global_variable << std::endl;      // The global_variable becomes 16! (it was 8);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`this` is a pointer to the current object. Dereferencing `this` gives you that object. When the return type of the function is a reference and you return an object, a reference to that object is returned instead. So, you are returning a reference to the object that you got from dereferencing `this` pointer. No reason for any warnings.

If you didn't dereference `this` pointer, then you'd get a compilation error because you'd be trying to return (a reference to) a pointer which would conflict with the return type of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but if you noticed I'm asking about why does this works?!-question. If you don't, I'm really really critical about understanding a code, it's ultimate necessity in programming, don't you think? 
Is this and Type& same thing?! Not operationally, but technically they're statements, right?! and they both represent hexadecimal number which is a pointer to an object. so, what's happening there is that this code returns object and the function makes type adjustment (because the function should return "reference to" type). Am I right?